# filter_var() parameter 2 as an string

Tags: php, validation

I'm using `filter_var` to filter some data types in PHP. I want to do this dynamic. I put an optional field in my model called filter, if I run my validate method I getting a PHP waring `Warning: filter_var() expects parameter 2 to be long`.

I'm think that is because I give the second parameter in `filter_var` with an string and it expects an constant. (see snippet)

**snippet**

```
 foreach($filters as $filter) {
     if($filter != "NO_FILTER") {
        var_dump(filter_var($var, trim($filter)));
     }
 }
```

**filter**

```
// var_dump($filter) = string(19) "FILTER_VALIDATE_URL"
```

The question is "Can I use a string in `filter_var()` or do I write an CASE for every filter possible?"

Comment: It expects one (or more) config constants or'd. String is not a constant, it's string. You'll have to find a way to get value of the constant from string.

Comment: Thanks @RoyalBg that's the solution!